# Prestashop 1.6.1.0 backoffice - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with `prestashop 1.6.1.0`. In backoffice when i open developer console, it gives me following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. I know this is happening because `admin.js` loading before `jQuery`.

I've spent some time to change script hierarchy on `Prestashop Backofffice`, but i couldn't find where are the scripts files located the end of bottom of document.

Here is the screenshot of my javascript hierarachy;

[image]

Does anyone knows where can i change included `scripts` **hierarchy?**

Thx in advance.

**### EDIT & UPDATE ###**

After @Sergii P 's answer and comments, i begin to search in my new theme's modules for solution. My theme added some new `modules` to my `backoffice`. So i've found this `override method` in my theme `controller`;

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader() {
        if (Tools::getValue('configure') == $this->name){
            $this->context->controller->addJquery();
        }
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'assets/css/admin.css');
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'assets/js/admin.js');
    }
```

How should i change this method?

And Here is the header.tpl for backoffice;

```
{if isset($css_files)}
{foreach from=$css_files key=css_uri item=media}
    <link href="{$css_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{/foreach}
{/if}
    {if (isset($js_def) && count($js_def) || isset($js_files) && count($js_files))}
        {include file=$smarty.const._PS_ALL_THEMES_DIR_|cat:"javascript.tpl"}
    {/if}

    {if isset($displayBackOfficeHeader)}
        {$displayBackOfficeHeader}
    {/if}
    {if isset($brightness)}
    <!--
        // @todo: multishop color
        <style type="text/css">
            div#header_infos, div#header_infos a#header_shopname, div#header_infos a#header_logout, div#header_infos a#header_foaccess {ldelim}color:{$brightness}{rdelim}
        </style>
    -->
    {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default jQuery always loaded first, 
and backoffice scripts loading you can find in `classes/controller/AdminController.php` method `setMedia` and there is:

```
        $this->addJquery();
        $this->addjQueryPlugin(array('scrollTo', 'alerts', 'chosen', 'autosize', 'fancybox' ));
        $this->addjQueryPlugin('growl', null, false);
        $this->addJqueryUI(array('ui.slider', 'ui.datepicker'));

        Media::addJsDef(array('host_mode' => (defined('_PS_HOST_MODE_') && _PS_HOST_MODE_)));

        $this->addJS(array(
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'admin.js',
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'tools.js',
            _PS_JS_DIR_.'jquery/plugins/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'
        ));
```

Comment: actually i have a new theme and it adds it's own admin.js to top of documents.

Comment: backoffice theme you mean? then check `header.tpl` in this theme and if admin.js hardcoded there just place it e.g. before `</head>` tag. I mean I see no toher ways to put admin.js above the jQuery - or change/override core files or hardcode path in tpl (I excluded exotic variants like creation html node from js), if you still have troubles show me related part of html + header.tpl of the backoffice theme

Comment: i'vde updated my question with screenshot of js hierarchy.

Comment: in your theme module change admin.js assign on something like `$this->addJS(array(100 => _PS_JS_DIR_.'admin.js'));` , just add bigger key value like 100 or more

Comment: i'vde updated my question, there's an override on `hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader` method. Can you please see my edit?

Comment: before I asked you to show me your theme header.tpl related parts, because in default theme `{$displayBackOfficeHeader}` apears below then $js_def/$js_files but, in any case, try to change line to next view `$this->context->controller->addJS(array(100 => $this->_path.'assets/js/admin.js'));`

Comment: i've added your code block to method, and didnt affected the error. I've updated my question with header.tpl file's head section. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hm, I was wrong with key index, but even using your update I got correct view, last idea, comment 2 lines `// if (Tools::getValue('configure') == $this->name){` and `// }` and leave only `$this->context->controller->addJquery();` it will try to add jQuery first. If this will not helps, I'll need to see your theme/module, just to avoid guessing

Answer (score 1):

First is running Controler::init() and there is call hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader(), after is running setMedia(); where is adding jq.

You need to call addJquery(); in hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader(),

```
    public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJquery(); //add jquery
    $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path.'views/js/js.js'); //add js
}
```